# LD_PRELOAD error when building core-image-minimal

Tags: linker, embedded-linux, linker-errors, bitbake

I started receiving LD_PRELOAD error, when I am building core-image-minimal:

```
ERROR: core-image-minimal-initramfs-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: [log_check] core-image-minimal-initramfs: found 1 error message in the logfile:
[log_check] ERROR: ld.so: object 'libpseudo.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: core-image-minimal-initramfs-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/jamal/test/panther_repo/build/tmp/work/panther2-poky-linux/core-image-minimal-initramfs/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.25212
```

Can you guys please help me to understand how to solve this issue. We are using sumo branch and meta-intel layer. I don't know how this error came, as everything was working fine and builds were getting successful recently

Comment: Maybe you need to install libpseudo?   A rootfs contains a lot of files that need to be owned by root which a normal user couldn't create on an actual filesystem, so to create an image to pack on the filesystem, they sort of fake the file permission by intercepting the actual access with the dynamic linker, and then fake them back when the archiver reads them... fakeroot is another similar idea.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you aren't wrong but Yocto/OE really should handle all of that, installing additional things should not be needed (libpseudo is included in oe-core and should just end up in the recipes native sysroot automatically)

Comment: it was working fine and somehow it started throw this error